# DB Browser for SQLite foreign key errors

Tags: foreign-key, sqlite

My Main Table is:

```
CREATE TABLE "STUDENT" (
    "last_name" TEXT NOT NULL,
    "first_name"    TEXT NOT NULL,
    "date_of_birth" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "email" TEXT,
    "race"  TEXT,
    "gender"    TEXT,
    "disability"    TEXT,
    "ethnicity" TEXT,
    "address"   REAL,
    PRIMARY KEY("last_name","first_name","date_of_birth")
);
```

These three other tables give me a foreign key error but two other tables work just fine. Here is an example of the error:

> foreign key mismatch - `NSF` referencing `STUDENT`
> (INSERT INTO "main"."NSF"("laste_name","first_name","date_of_birth","train_start_year","train_start_semester")VALUES('Doe','John','01/01/2000','2020','fall');)

```
CREATE TABLE "ATTENDS" (
    "last_name" TEXT NOT NULL,
    "first_name"    TEXT NOT NULL,
    "date_of_birth" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "train_status"  TEXT NOT NULL,
    "semester"  TEXT NOT NULL,
    "semester_year" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "class" TEXT NOT NULL,
    "scholarship_amount"    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "gpa"   INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "transfer_date" INTEGER,
    "program_name"  TEXT,
    "intern"    TEXT,
    "graduated" TEXT,
    "further_education" TEXT,
    "working_in_stem"   TEXT,
    "nature_job"    TEXT,
    "company_name"  TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY("last_name","first_name","date_of_birth","train_status"),
    FOREIGN KEY("date_of_birth") REFERENCES "STUDENT"("date_of_birth"),
    FOREIGN KEY("first_name") REFERENCES "STUDENT"("first_name"),
    FOREIGN KEY("last_name") REFERENCES "STUDENT"("last_name")
);
```

```
CREATE TABLE "NSF" (
    "last_name" TEXT NOT NULL,
    "first_name"    TEXT NOT NULL,
    "date_of_birth" TEXT NOT NULL,
    "train_start_year"  TEXT NOT NULL,
    "train_start_semester"  TEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY("last_name","first_name","date_of_birth","train_start_year"),
    FOREIGN KEY("first_name") REFERENCES "STUDENT"("first_name"),
    FOREIGN KEY("date_of_birth") REFERENCES "STUDENT"("date_of_birth"),
    FOREIGN KEY("last_name") REFERENCES "STUDENT"("last_name")
);
```

```
CREATE TABLE "SURVEY" (
    "last_name" TEXT NOT NULL,
    "first_name"    TEXT NOT NULL,
    "date_of_birth" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "semester_month"    TEXT,
    "semester_year" INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY("last_name","first_name","date_of_birth","semester_month","semester_year"),
    FOREIGN KEY("date_of_birth") REFERENCES "STUDENT"("date_of_birth"),
    FOREIGN KEY("semester_year") REFERENCES "RESPONSE"("semester_year"),
    FOREIGN KEY("first_name") REFERENCES "STUDENT"("first_name"),
    FOREIGN KEY("semester_month") REFERENCES "RESPONSE"("semester"),
    FOREIGN KEY("last_name") REFERENCES "STUDENT"("last_name")
);
```